# tmux: get names of panes, each current directory and history

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

my tmux session is a bit broken, by which I mean that `tmux ls` returns an error like `error connecting to /private/var/folders/d0/xbg08_x12lddw3dkht5w462c0000gn/T/tmux-501/default (No such file or directory)`

I normally use `tmux-resurrect` to save all my panels names, current directory and history, but due to this `error connecting to ...` that plug-in does not work.

I was wondering if I can, with some automation, obtain the names of the panes and their current directory, and possibly even their history, or I am doomed to note them down by hand or loose them (I got 30+ panes now ... )

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: even getting the current directory shown in the "chose-window" menu would be helpful, but I cannot find a way to do that either!

Comment: I have made some progress with `list-panes -s -F '#{window_index} #{pane_index} #{pane_current_path}'` which shows window and pane numbers and path of each pane.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310). Two possibilities: (1) The missing file was a socket necessary for communication with the tmux server, it has been deleted. The right thing is to tell the server to recreate it; you can do this by sending SIGUSR1 to the tmux server process. (Note this won't recreate directories, you may need to do this by hand, beforehand.) (2) Or maybe `$TMUX` or `$TMUX_TMPDIR` are wrong for some reason and your `tmux ls` cannot find the right *existing* socket. Locate the socket and fix the variable(s) (or use `tmux -S … ls`).